# Content causes div displacement

Tags: html, css

When adding content 'P' to a tile div it cause a displacement of said div. The divs only have to be able contain 1 character each. Any better methods of achieving a pyramid of stacked circles are also welcome.

https://jsfiddle.net/usm9t60r/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tile circle">P</div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tile circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body { 
    font-size: 62.5%; 
}

.container {
    min-width: 32rem;
    max-width: 96rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
}

.circle {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've styled each `.circle` element with `display:inline-block`, and the default value for [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is `baseline`, adding text to an element makes it align to the baseline of other elements.

I had success by adding `vertical-align:top` to the `.circle` class.

```css
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
.container {
  min-width: 32rem;
  max-width: 96rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
}
.circle {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="circle">P</div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a space character inside

```
<div class="tile circle">&nbsp;</div>
```